# defining a list of generic objects in c#

Tags: c#, struct

I am trying to find the cleanest way to construct an objet that contains a list of other objects as well as a few more entries like Struct and an int in c#

```
Class Object0
{
      int   Counter0
      Object[]  An Array of Object1
}
Class Object
{
      String   Header1
      String[] Detail
}
```

===================================

Is this any good?

```
namespace ObjectCreation
{
public class Object
{
    public Object()
    {
        this.Records = new List<string>();
    }
    public void AddARecord(string record)
    {
        Records.Add(record);
    }
    private string _Header;
    private List<string> Records;
    public string Header { get { return _Header; } set { _Header = value; } }
}
public class ObjectList
{
    int _Counter;
    private List<Object> _objectlist;
    public ObjectList()
    {
        _objectlist = new List<Object>();
        _Counter = 0;
    }
    public void AddObject(Object o)
    {
        _objectlist.Add(o);
        _Counter++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the ArrayList?

Comment: List<Object> objs = new List<Object>();

Answer (score 0):

To create an object that contains more objects as well as `ints` and `structs`, you should use `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Object>();`. This is an index-based list with which you can access objects by their position in the list, and it is capable of storing any variable using its `Add(item)` method.

Comment: If you're going to create `List<Object>` why not bypass generics altogether and just use `ArrayList`? The type of each item is already `Object` and you avoid the overhead of generics.

Comment: I simply prefer to use generic classes and tend to avoid `ArrayList`. I've had a few experiences where I was developing on edge case .NET platforms, and `List<Object>` was available while `ArrayList` was not. That might have been simply because I was doing something wrong, though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "edge case .NET platforms" but ArrayList has been around since .NET 1.1 while generics were introduced in .NET 2.0, so if anything I'd think the System.Collections namespace would have broader support than System.Collections.Generic. The one exception it appears is Silverlight. I just generally prefer choosing the right tool for the job/situation.